# Can't get jupyter + conda + packages to work

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to run jupyter notebook on conda with some package likes scipy.

While `conda install scipy` says that `scipy` is installed:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at ...\Continuum\Anaconda3:
#
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py35_1
```

`jupyter` says this, when I do `from scipy import ndimage`:

```
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I run `jupyter` with `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: Have you checked your `python path`? Maybe anaconda's python isn't the default python version.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall scipy
conda install scipy
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Trying uninstalling ``scipy`` using ``pip`` is leading to ``Cannot uninstall requirement scipy, not installed``.